# Variation Hierarchies not getting created

Tags: sharepoint-online, variations

I have submitted a request for getting hierarchies created for my variations in my SharePoint online site. However, even after a day when I check out the variation logs, it states that :"The timer job create variation hierarchies is submitted.". The status hasn't changed even after a day of the submission. Any thoughts on whether I'd have to trigger something additionally.